# Technique for ensuring HTML- and URL-encoding

Tags: html, url, templates, encoding

Has anyone implemented a good system for ensuring that output is properly HTML-encoded where it makes sense? Maybe even something that recognizes when output should be URL-encoded or JSON-encoded instead?

The lazy approach — just encoding all inputs — causes problems when you want to send those inputs to a database, or to a block of JavaScript code. So something a little smarter is needed.

The tedious approach — putting the proper encoding function around each piece of data on the template — works, but it's easy for developers to forget to do it.

Is there a good approach that makes it easy for developers, and ensures that the right encoding is done? I was listening to one of the SO podcasts, and Joel tossed out an idea about using typed data to enforce a difference between HTML-encoded strings and non-encoded strings. Maybe that could be a starting point.

I'm looking more for a strategy than for an implementation in a particular language (although I'd be happy to hear about implementations that already exist and work).

**EDIT:** Here are some links I've found so far:

- [A type-based solution to the "strings problem"](http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/10/18/a-type-based-solution-to-the-strings-problem)
- [String::Smart](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/String-Smart/lib/String/Smart.pm)
- [Reducing XSS by way of Automatic Context-Aware Escaping in Template Systems](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2009/03/reducing-xss-by-way-of-automatic.html)
- [Secure String Interpolation in JS](http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/changes/mikesamuel/string-interpolation-29-Jan-2008/trunk/src/js/com/google/caja/interp/index.html)

Comment: What server-side language, what platform(s) are you talking about? That is necessary info IMO if you want detailed answers.

Comment: I'm using PHP, but see the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Data that goes into your database probably should not have any escaping for HTML, JavaScript, or what have you. If you *do* include markup, you'll just have to strip it out if you decide to inject this data into a CSV file or PDF, etc...

Instead, whenever you query 'raw' data like this out of the database, escape the data at that time as appropriate to wherever you're injecting it; HTML, a JavaScript string, server-side scripting, etc.